# In grails 2 when using multiple datasources, can I specify which datasource a criteria should use?

Tags: grails-orm, criteria, grails-2.0

In my grails 2 application I have multiple datasources configured in Datasources.groovy.  My domain class mappings specify that all datasources should be used

```
class Book {
    static mapping = { datasource 'ALL' }
```

For basic Gorm calls I am able to specify which datasource to use.

`Book.lookup.save()`  correctly uses the 'lookup' datasource

**Is there a way to specify which datasource a criteria should use?**

I have tried the following 4 solutions without any luck

1. `def c = Book.lookup.createCriteria(); c.list{...`

   The call to .list throws: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
2. `def c = Book.createCriteria(); c.lookup.list{...`
   no such method
3. Injecting the datasource

   `def dataSource_lookup`

   ...

   `Book.createCriteria(dataSource_lookup)`
   no such method
4. Specifying that the whole service where the criteria is located should use a specific datasource doesn't seem to be working for the criteria nor for the basic save() call.  I'm running grails 2.1.0.

   `static datasource = 'lookup'`

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution, however it does work if you access the datasource beforehand (presumably within the same hibernate session).

```
Book.lookup.read(1)
def c = Book.lookup.createCriteria()
c.list{...
```